# Unable to build angular project - Proper does not exist on component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having an issue I do not understand at all. I am fairly new angular so it may be something small but never the less.

When I try to build my project to publish it to a github page, the HTML components are failing on the build as the properties from the component do not exist. All of the errors relate to the HTML components not being away of the object properties. (Which are provided via an API service anyway!)

I have attempted to provide the minimum required code to illustrate the problem.

Error Dump:

```
ERROR in src\app\users\users.component.html(4,20): : Property 'queryString' does not exist on type 'UsersComponent'.
src\app\users\users.component.html(9,7): : Property 'queryString' does not exist on type 'UsersComponent'.
src\app\users\users.component.html(4,20): : Property 'queryString' does not exist on type 'UsersComponent'.
src\app\details\details.component.html(1,5): : Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src\app\details\details.component.html(4,32): : Property 'RunnerName' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src\app\details\details.component.html(5,29): : Property 'LastTime' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src\app\details\details.component.html(6,29): : Property 'LastDistance' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src\app\details\details.component.html(7,29): : Property 'date' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

user.component.html

```
<h1>Runners</h1>

<div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="queryString" placeholder = "Search Runner Name">
</div>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor = "let user of users | filterdata: queryString : 'RunnerName' ; let i = index">

    <a routerLink = "/details/{{ user.RunnerId }}">{{ user.RunnerName }}</a>

    <ul>
      <li><strong>Runner ID: {{ user.RunnerId }}</strong></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//Importing my users service, up one level in project structure from here.
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
//RXJS will hold the data which is returned from the API...
//RESEARCH RXJS
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})

//Export class implenets OnInit.
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  //Prop which holds returned API data
  //of type obect.
  users: Object;

  //Creating instance of the service via dependancy injection.
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  //NG on init is one of the "lifecycle hooks" for angular components.
  //Code in here will be executed when the component loads for ngOnInit.
  ngOnInit() {
    //Executing the method which is provided by the service.
    //Adding data bind via subscribe.
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(
      //returning the user data via single line return function
      //passing the data value into the function.
      (data) => {
      //assinging the data to the user object.
      this.users = data
      //sorting the users object by runner ID.
      //this.users.sort((a,b) => a.RunnerId - b.RunnerId);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//Importing te angular HTTP Client
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

//Class which exports the service to the APP.
//We will import this class into the components when required.
export class DataService {

  //Utilising the HTTP client import Class
  //HTTP Client request expects JSON return data as default, their is no need to parse JSON anymore.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  //Custom Method to return Users collection from the web API.
  getUsers(){
    //single line return statement.
    return this.http.get('http://rundistance.azurewebsites.net/api/RunnerService')
  }
  //Function to return the detail of a single user, passing in the ID prop of currently selected target of objects master layer.
  getUser(userId){
    //single line return statement getting target object from API.
    return this.http.get('http://rundistance.azurewebsites.net/api/RunnerService/'+userId)
  }
  //Returning posts from API.
  getPosts(){
    //single line return statement.
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  }
}
```

filterdata.pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterdata'
})

export class FilterdataPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], value: string, label:string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];

    if (!value) return  items;

    if (value == '' || value == null) return [];
    return items.filter(e => e[label].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 );
  }

}
```

Comment: The error is correct; that property does not exist on that component. What is unclear?

Comment: When I serve the project locally, this does not happen. The the object properties which are then iteratted over are supplied by the service. This is what I dont understand, those object properties cannot exist until the api is called.

Comment: The only thing you show it getting from the service is `users` (which you've typed, unhelpfully, as Object - you should work *with* TypeScript, so it can give you useful errors like the one you're asking about).

Comment: The users returned from the get request is an object, I had assumed this would build correctly as it works completely as required when served locally.

Comment: queryString isn't from or related to that object, though. Angular is intentionally more lenient in dev mode. All you need to do is *actually define the props you're using*. I'd recommend turning TS strict mode on *and listening to it*.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Thanks, I will chug over it now.

Comment: Well the query string one I just define query string in the component.ts but when trying enter name onto my details component I have the same errors.

Comment: Read the error message; that's a different problem from queryString. Again, typing as Object is **not** helping. I'd recommend reading introductory resources on Angular and TypeScript before continuing.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with typing, just use type `any`, not recommended/best practices on typescript. I would just defined your types.

Comment: Thanks, I have got it all working now. Just trying to deploy the app next.